# Disable Android N display size / screen zoom changing in my app

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

Android N has display size / screen zoom feature.

To handle multiple screen size in devices, I use many dimens.xml (ldpi - mdpi - hdpi - xhdpi - xxhdpi - xxxhdpi), but in Android N devices, such as Galaxy S6, when the user changes the display size / screen zoom, I can't handle that.

Is there any manifest tag or others to disable this feature in my app?

**UPDATE**
this is Display metrics on two mode:

```
DisplayMetrics{density=4.0, width=1440, height=2560, scaledDensity=4.0, xdpi=580.571, ydpi=580.571}
DisplayMetrics{density=4.5, width=1440, height=2560, scaledDensity=4.5, xdpi=580.571, ydpi=580.571}
```

Answer (score -1):

set in   tag in manifest for disable multiscreen for activity

android:resizeableActivity="false"

Comment: That is for multi window - not for display-size according to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window